# Insert data in wordpress by clicking on the button

Tags: sql, ajax, wordpress

I can not insert this in wordpress. Does not insert anything.If you can help me thank you

How can I do this in ajax?

```html
  <input type="submit" name="" value="" id="boton1" onclick = "rating();">

              <?php
              function rating(){
                  global $wpdb;
               $wpdb->insert( 'rating', 
                 array( 
                    'rating_postid'=>'120', 
                    'rating_posttitle'=>'title',
                    'rating_rating'=>'5'                  
                  )
                ); 
              }  
              add_action('wp', 'rating');
  
              ?>
```

Comment: Your understanding of the separation between server-side (PHP) and client-side (Javascript) code is flawed - having `onclick = "rating();"` in your HTML will trigger a **Javascript** function named `rating()`. This does not have any ability to trigger the PHP code you've posted alongside.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some Javascript to bridge your HTML `rating()` call and your PHP code. Re-name your `add_action` function to be prefixed with `wp_ajax_` (and a more descriptive action name):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_rating', 'rating');
```

Then add a localization string to point your Javascript file to the right `admin-ajax.php` file:

```
wp_localize_script( "ajax-script", "ajaxurl", admin_url("admin-ajax.php"));
```

Finally, define a Javascript function (in your case, `rating()` as you've already called it) in a file that will be output to the user on pages where this functionality can be invoked that POSTs data to `wp_ajax.php`:

```
function rating() {
    var data = {
        'action': 'rating'
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
}
```

You should review [the documentation WordPress provides on this topic](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).